# Line in loop not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var games = [];
var numbers_to_letters = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]

function Game(){
    roll_animation();
}

$("#roll_dice").click(function(){
    games.push(new Game());
});

function roll_animation(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            (function(ind){
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".btn.btn-die").addClass(numbers_to_letters[ind+1]).removeClass(numbers_to_letters[ind]);
                }, 20 * (ind + 1));
            })(j);
        }
        $(".btn.btn-die").addClass("one").removeClass("six");
    }
}
```

The last line in the first loop doesn't get executed unless I press the button again, resulting in the second loop only running once. (it needs a reset to work again) Why doesn't the last line always get executed?

Comment: The `setTimeout` doesn't block, so that last line is going to be run all 100 times before the first `setTimeout` code runs.

Comment: ...also, all your `setTimeout` calls are going to run at just about the same time, but with a 20ms offset.

Comment: @cookie monster, why is this? that's not how loops work in every other language i've worked in. how do you make it block so it runs from top to bottom?

Comment: @user3348360: It has nothing to do with the loop. In fact, the loop *is* behaving like normal loops. The difference is the `setTimeout`, which schedules code to run later. It can't block, because if it did, it would block the UI. So that's definitely not what you want. Basically you need to not use `for` loops and just schedule the next action from within the `setTimeout` callback, and maintain the counter there as well. Each callback will increment the counter, and make a call to a function that does the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue of asynchronous code in the `setTimeout()` function running some time later and thus not synchronized with the other code in the loops.

The line of code in question:

```
$(".btn.btn-die").addClass("one").removeClass("six");
```

is running just fine.  But, because the `setTimeout()` calls are scheduled for execution some timer LATER, they all run after this above line runs.  So this line of code runs and then the `setTimeout()` timers start firing and the effect of the above line is overwritten.  This is what your code has instructed it to do.

If you slow the times down, you can see what is happening here in this demo of your codde: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tqYq7/

If, what you want is for the above line of code to run AFTER the last timer fires, then you need to write your code to do that instead of the way you have it written now.  It's unclear to me what you're trying to do with this line of code anyway so I am not sure exactly what to recommend.

One might ask why you're setting 500 timers too, most of which are going to go off at the exact same time and run the exact same code?  There are certainly more efficient ways to run something in a recurring fashion.  If what you're really trying to do is to run the inner animation 100 times, one after the other, then you will have to code completely differently because what you're doing now is setting 100 copies of the same timers all scheduled to go off at the same time.

Here's a demo for a different way to program it that doesn't have the issues yours does.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zsa8m/

```
var games = [];
var numbers_to_letters = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];

function Game(){
    roll_animation();
}

$("#roll_dice").click(function(){
    games.push(new Game());
});

function roll_animation(){
    var cntr = 0;

    function next() {
        var die = cntr % 6;
        var nextDie = (die + 1) % 6;
        $(".btn.btn-die")
            .addClass(numbers_to_letters[nextDie])
            .removeClass(numbers_to_letters[die]);
        ++cntr;
        // keep going as long as cntr < 100 and we aren't on number 1
        // so that the die always end on 1
        if (cntr < 100 || nextDie != 0) {
            setTimeout(next, 50);
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

You can obviously change the constants to suit your purposes.

Just for grins, here's a version that rolls randomly rather than sequentially: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NSW8U/

Comment: The inner for loop is suppose to change the class from one to six, and the last line to reset the class back to one so the inner loop can repeat again. It's for an animation effect.

Comment: @user3348360 - the last line of code is running BEFORE any of your timers run.  Do you understand that the timer code runs sometime in the future?  The last line of code runs right now before the timers.  And your outer loop is accomplishing nothing right now.  You will have to write that if you want to actually repeat the animation 100 times.

Comment: Yes I understood that, but I have no idea. I thought of the setTimeout function as an equivalent to a wait function, but I understand now that it works completely different.

Comment: @user3348360 - `setTimeout()` is NOT a wait function.  It schedules code to be run in the future and then the code right after it executes right now.  So your double loops are just scheduling a whole bunch of things to be run in the future (mostly all at the same time).  See the code and demo I've added to my answer for an alternative way to code this.